# Ember data changes in parent component not refelecting on UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a parent component which has an accordion panel (with multiple/dynamic number of rows)

```
{{#my-accordion accordionPanels=accordionPanels as |accordion| }}
{{my-details-row section=accordion.props.section removeRow='removeRow'}}
{{/my-accordion}}
```

The corresponding JS is as below;

```
accordionPanels: function() {
    var accordionPanels = [];
    var self = this;
    var myRows = this.get('section').myRows;
    myRows.forEach(function(myRow) {
        accordionPanels.pushObject({
            panel: {
                name: myRow.rowId,
                props: {
                    section: myRow
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return accordionPanels;
}.property('section.myRows'),

actions: {
    removeRow: function(row){
        var numberContainers = this.get('section').myRows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numberContainers; i++){
            if(this.get('section').myRows.contains(row.name)){
                console.log("row found!");
                this.get('section').myRows.removeObject(row.name);
            }
        }
    },
}
```

The child component (my-details-row) code is as below

```
actions: {
    removeRow: function(row){
        this.sendAction('removeRow', row);
    }
}
```

The child hbs is as below;

```
<div class="dataBlockItem">
    {{my-field field=(field-from-section section "SECTION_NAME" "FIELD_NAME") }}
</div>  
{{my-button label="Remove" action="removeRow"}}
```

Now when the Remove button is clicked, I want the corresponding row to be removed. While I do get the action in the parent (passed from child), 
even after executing the line

> this.get('section').myRows.removeObject(row.name);

The UI does not get updated (i.e. the data changes in the parent do not reflect in the child component)

Do I need to write additional code/logic to be able to reflect the changes on the UI ?

Comment: Try `this.get('section.myRows').removeObject(row.name);`, if you want observer and computed property to trigger then you need to use `get` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You should be able to use closure actions to help simplify connecting the parent and child component actions. Please see the below code and a very basic example Ember Twiddle at the link below. Also, you may have seen this, but just in case here is a link to the Ember.js guides that provides an explanation of component actions. [Ember Component Actions -version 2.15](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/)

Parent component.hbs

```
{{#my-accordion accordionPanels=accordionPanels as |accordion| }}
  {{my-details-row section=accordion.props.section removeRow=(action 'removeRow' accordion)}}
{{/my-accordion}}
```

Parent component.js

--here the row can be removed by simply passing the row object itself `.removedObject(row)`

```
actions: {
  removeRow: function(row){
    var numberContainers = this.get('section.myRows').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberContainers; i++){
      if(this.get('section.myRows').includes(row.name)){
        console.log("row found!");
        this.get('section.myRows').removeObject(row);
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Child component.hbs

--here tie the `removeRow` action to the button component's click event

```
<div class="dataBlockItem">
    {{my-field field=(field-from-section section "SECTION_NAME" "FIELD_NAME") }}
</div>  
{{my-button label="Remove" click=removeRow}}
```

Child component.js

--here the `removeRow` function does not have to be defined.

```
actions: {
  // No need to define the removeRow function
}
```

[Example Ember Twiddle --using ember.js@2.2.2 to show the rough compatibility of the above approach](https://ember-twiddle.com/1a2aabc84aff4cf86ae2f0b2a4087e40?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.button-component.hbs)

Comment: Thanks for that awesome reply...Just one question...Does the param name for the action also have to be passed while referring the child component in the hbs i.e. accordion in this case

Comment: In this case, the `accordion` object passed to the action only has to be passed to the child in the parent component.hbs. Please let me know if this answer does not fit your question.